# ViewGroup exception: parameter must be a descendant of this view

Tags: android, viewgroup

I was looking through my exception log from users and found this common exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
   at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:2521)
   at android.view.FocusFinder.findNearestTouchable(FocusFinder.java:411)
   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1746)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there some way I can gracefully handle this exception and prevent a Force Close?  I can't reproduce the problem.

[I found this Google thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/04e2a2ac4d363d1f) about it being a problem with Donut (1.5) and it was fixed. But I'm getting this from users using later versions of Android.  My min API is to 1.6 and targeted at 2.2.

Comment: Any indication of what (in your code) is causing it?

Comment: @MistSquonk Not that I'm aware. The stacktrace isn't pointing to any part of my code. My guess is it might be the (Safe)ViewFlipper I'm using?

Comment: Backtrace shows a handler involved. Are posting any event to Handler?. Look like by the time message gets dispatched, the View got invalid or lost focus.

Comment: @Sukumar I'm using a ViewFlipper + Gestures to "flip" left or right to other views, so maybe they went to a new activity before it finished processing the motion event/gesture?

Comment: Yup, I think so. Look into the your Handler's code and check it has any references to parent View/Activity. Or try surrounding the handler's code in Exception.

Comment: If you are using ListView, try my way:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12888761/1745885

Answer (score 0):

My guess : It could be that offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords() is trying to get the coordinates of a grand child, ie: the child it is looking for is not a direct descendant of the viewgroup caller.

Answer (score 0):

I've just met this similar problem.

I found that what findFocus() returns, is not a child or descendant of rootView.

So, if indexOfChild() returns -1, I simply pass null as 2nd param (focused) to findNextFocus() of FocusFinder.