# Listview Scrolling crashes - parameter must be a descendant of this view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a simple listview with one image when i scroll the listview it crashes with the below error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:4884)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:4821)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder.init(ViewGroup.java:7239)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder.obtain(ViewGroup.java:7173)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.ViewGroup$ChildListForAccessibility.init(ViewGroup.java:7108)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.ViewGroup$ChildListForAccessibility.obtain(ViewGroup.java:7076)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addChildrenForAccessibility(ViewGroup.java:1884)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.ViewGroup.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(ViewGroup.java:2766)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:5532)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.widget.AdapterView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AdapterView.java:941)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AbsListView.java:1493)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.widget.ListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(ListView.java:3882)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:5493)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:5480)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchSiblingsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1028)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:885)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:155)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$400(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:53)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1236)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
05-19 18:57:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

I have looked into few threads related to this issue, but didnt help me .

Can anyone suggest me what exactly its trying to tell me ?

**EDIT 1**

List view

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>
```

Image View :

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/img" />
```

Comment: Post your code too, not just your logcat.

Comment: @BidhanA Its just a simple list view with Image view in it.

Comment: @BidhanA i have just added the layout please see my edit

Comment: Where is your imageView? Please post your complete layout(s).

Comment: It seems related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100555/preventing-catching-illegalargumentexception-parameter-must-be-a-descendant-of/12892317#12892317

Comment: @timwashere i have tried that as well but its not working

Comment: Please post your entire layout file, not just individual items. Also, post your Java code.

Comment: When your view is not visible on the screen by scrolling, throws IllegalArgumentException. Because ListView recycles the views. So your view is always not descendant.