# Kotlin Scrollview throwing Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Kotlin android app, that has a big scroll view with a bunch of dynamically loaded images laying on the scroll view (also an admob ads). The goal is to have a scrollable as well as pinch-and-zoomable list of images.

Some users (not many, but hundreds) are experiencing the following crash:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
  at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild (ViewGroup.java:6405)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords (ViewGroup.java:6330)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.isWithinDeltaOfScreen (ScrollView.java:1315)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.onSizeChanged (ScrollView.java:1730)
  at android.view.View.sizeChange (View.java:23918)
  at android.view.View.setFrame (View.java:23870)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23717)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6522)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23722)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6522)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout (ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23722)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6522)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23722)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6522)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1829)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23722)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6522)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23722)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6522)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1829)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23722)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6522)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:866)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23722)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6522)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:4048)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3467)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2384)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:9362)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1168)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:920)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:835)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1150)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:210)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:299)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8290)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:577)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1073)
```

I found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100555/preventing-catching-illegalargumentexception-parameter-must-be-a-descendant-of) on this but the thread is largely talking about textfield focus, while my app does not even have any text field.

I can't reproduce the issue regardless of what I try. Anyone has a clue of what could be causing the problem and how I may reproduce this, and solve this?

Comment: have you solved it its happening to me now

Comment: @AbuQudama unfortunately, haven't solved it

Comment: i think i have got solution i already implemented we will see in coming days if error persist refer to this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230950647?pli=1  there is solution on final page.